# Set all values in a mutableStateMap to a default value without the replaceAll{} or forEach{} collections

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, collections

So I have a problem in Android Studio where the use of the replaceAll{} and forEach{} collections on a mutableStateMap requires minimum level of SDK 24. This is a legacy codebase and cannot move off 23 for now.

A brief example of how I've tried to use it is below

```
        val mapOfBoxToCheckedState = remember {
            mutableStateMapOf<String, Boolean>(

                *eventSummaryContentModel.eventList.map {
                    Pair(
                        it.event.details.eventId,
                        false
                    )
                }.toTypedArray()
            )
        }


        fun uncheckAllCheckboxes(
            success : Boolean
        ){
            if(success){
                mapOfBoxToCheckedState.replaceAll{ _, _ -> false}
            }
        }
```

It's the same story when I try to use the forEach collection, requires minimum SDK 24 apparently. Simply adding the @RequiresAPI(N) is not a viable workaround at this time.

Am I missing anything obvious here? Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: You need to target Java 8 and enable desugaring. See the instructions here. https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

Answer (score 1):

To use Java-8 specific functions, you need to target Java 8 and enable desugaring. See the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support).

There's no `replaceAll` in the Kotlin standard library, but you should be able to use Kotlin's `forEach`, which is more efficient than Java's version. Make sure you only define one lambda parameter, or use a destructuring declaration, such as:

```
someMap.forEach { (key, value) ->
    // do something
}
```

Note the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

I think may be there is something wrong with your dependencies. But if so it will take longer for to understand, so for simple solution I would advise you to use ordinary for block, smth like this ->

```
fun uncheckAllCheckboxes(success : Boolean) {
    if(success) {
       val keys = map.keys()
       for(key in keys) {
          map[key] = false
       }
    }
}
```